# Replace the injected HttpContext for class in application

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, httpcontext, mediatr

I'm setting up some integration tests for mediatr handlers using xunit, respawn, and webapplicationfactory....

One of classes ultimately called by the mediatr handler that is being tested.. has a dependency on IHttpContextAccessor as you can see below

[image]

I feel like I've set up the "replacement" singleton that I want injected correctly as per below:

[image]

But when the integration test runs.. the httpContextAccessor is not null but the HttpContext is ALWAYS null.

I've tried about 6 million things :( Much sadness.

How can get the IHttpContextAccessor to resolve correctly to what I'm setting in ConfigureServices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to implement IHttpContextAccessor myself

[image]

Then utilise in the ConfigureTestServices of the WebApplicationFactory ConfigureWebHost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When the integration test runs.. the httpContextAccessor is not null but the HttpContext is ALWAYS null.How can get the IHttpContextAccessor to resolve correctly to what I'm
> setting in ConfigureServices?

No we cannot, The HttpContext will only be available within the scope of the request because ConfigureServices invocked before constructing Startup so if we try to inject, it will through exception, even if we declare at global variable in that scenario it will always be null. Application startup happens only once, and long before any request has been received.

Let's try to access it within IConfiguration as following:

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;


        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }
```

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't allow us to do so.

Even if we try to inject it within configuration itself it will ended up with following exception:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, ConfigureServices runs once before any httprequest coming to application. If we forcefully try to call it outside of request life-cycle it will always ended up with NullReferenceException. You can [get more details in the official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

In addition to this, we can inject service reference within configuration as following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: thanks for responding... so what's a man to do? Set up the integration tests to come via a httpClient into my webapplicationfactory and have an actual httpcontext?

Comment: They usually create a custom ControllerContext for tests that can contain an HTTP context. Note that, it uses HttpContextBase which you can inherit and even mock a completely custom HTTP context in your test. I would recommed you to [`check this official dcoument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0). In addition, frankly speaking, I a novice dev with least expertise on testing. Thanks for your response. Document might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me as well, but my issue was that I was accidentally adding:
`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
inside the `ConfigureTestServices` method. So the final setup should look like this (because the accepted answer has images instead of code):

MockHttpContextAccessor.cs

```
public class MockHttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
{
    HttpContext? IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext { get; set; } = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        User = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("test-user"), new[] { "sample-role" })
    };
}
```

ConfigureWebHost method inside the WebApplicationFactory class:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, MockHttpContextAccessor>();
    });
}
```